# Magento navigation menu but not added as Category

Tags: magento

I am very new in Magento.Actually we have a client who has purchased a Magento theme and top navigation of theme is displaying some menu links like delivery,Contact Us and these are not added as Categories.May be hard coded in the theme.Can anyone tell from which file these links are appearing so that i can edit them.

Comment: most probably they are cms  pages. Check in `CMS -> Pages` (ADMIN side). Probably you can find those contact us page

Comment: @programmer_rkt There is no such page.

Comment: check in static blocks then. `CMS->Static Blocks`

Comment: Already checked but no result.

Comment: can you provide link of the site. Need to check the content inside those menus

Answer (score 0):

Use template path hints to find out where they are.
http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-turning-on-template-path-hints/